# Is anyone using Maven/NAR for any large scale C/C++ projects?

Tags: c++, c, build, makefile, maven

And, what has your experience been?  Do you think that Maven has been well suited to your project, and how would you advise others on following your path?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wanted to ask whether you'd had any success down this path?

Comment: Yes, packaging or building over 200 artifacts on windows, largely C++ with mixed in Java, C#, Javascript.  Initial plan was to build up to a final package using 1 'artifact' model.  Due to initial mess, changed plan and worked back by bulk packaging all the binaries from the old build and working to extract the individual artifacts from the mess.

Answer (score 3):

CERN seems to be using it in combination with Make:

http://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/icalepcs2011/papers/wepks026.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I have not used Maven for any of my projects but some of my colleagues used for java projects. Are you looking for ant special features of it ? if its plain vanilla build then stick with Makefiles. You can also look at http://www.scons.org/

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use maven for a C/C++ project?
Maven is very good but require you a very deep knowledge, and it is strongly Java-oriented.
I think Makefiles are good also for big C++ project.

I will suggest automake+autoconf for a slight better way of managing Makefile creation.

Take also a look to big project like the OpenOffice sources, for getting inspired.

Comment: Thank you - I don't want to bias any further results or responses but let's say I'm looking for any evidence that this is a Good Idea.

Comment: As someone who has worked with medium-sized codebases in both languages, I can say that library versioning and dependency management become important if you are not using a continuous build process and have many executables.  I strongly prefer make over ant, and I tend to dislike having lots of XML config files lying around, but I wish that maven could be made to play nicely with C/C++ so that I can have any easy way to manage library versions and dependencies.

Comment: [NAR?](http://duns.github.com/maven-nar-plugin/index.html)

Comment: If you're interested in one person's opinion of autotools, checkout this blog post by Jussi Pakkanen.  At the end he suggests CMake as an alternative. http://voices.canonical.com/jussi.pakkanen/2011/09/13/autotools/.  To balance, some are not happy with CMake either https://stackoverflow.com/a/3541156/110126.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using CMake under Maven: http://code.google.com/p/cmake-maven-project/

I find CMake much easier to use because it generates full-fledged project files. You can then open those project files and run the debugger, profiler, etc.